# glmer warning messages in lme4 in r

Tags: lme4

I'm running a negative binomial glmer using lme4. I am getting some errors that I can see others have had in the past but I can't work out how to apply those solutions to my own model.

The errors are as follows:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ...:
    Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00827217 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
    2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  ... :
    Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
    - Rescale variables?
```

I have included my data with reproducible code below:

```
    abglmm.nb<-glmer.nb(Ab~Treatment*Struc+(1|Site),data=y)
    y<-structure(list(Site = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Gar", 
    "Ing", "Mal"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Cag", "Hshg", "Lshg", "Nog"), class = "factor"), 
    Struc = c(72.28753968, 70.31960317, 57.22154762, 43.36305556, 
    55.09400794, 48.89420635, 68.52, 75.9256746, 65.8225, 43.45376984, 
    52.08833333, 30.52218254, 23.37588999, 21.27666667, 17.72349206, 
    26.48095238, 32.26884921, 40.57555556, 19.39702381, 15.24972222, 
    13.3684127, 32.06484127, 31.15543651, 31.92099206, 37.10579365, 
    39.91400794, 56.26515873, 11.0725, 15.39166667, 14.11166667, 
    20.03650794, 18.80099206, 21.7102381, 17.47722222, 15.18083333, 
    12.2865873), Ab = c(393L, 554L, 317L, 249L, 455L, 371L, 488L, 
    353L, 544L, 393L, 443L, 475L, 608L, 715L, 583L, 650L, 433L, 
    428L, 447L, 402L, 411L, 541L, 692L, 632L, 589L, 564L, 569L, 
    457L, 386L, 527L, 251L, 454L, 471L, 394L, 231L, 378L)), .Names = c("Site", 
    "Treatment", "Struc", "Ab"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("BU1", 
    "BU2", "BU3", "JU1", "JU2", "JU3", "GU1", "GU2", "GU3", "KC1", 
    "KC2", "KC3", "HC1", "HC2", "HC3", "GC1", "GC2", "GC3", "OL1", 
    "OL2", "OL3", "ML1", "ML2", "ML3", "GL1", "GL2", "GL3", "TH1", 
    "TH2", "TH3", "KH1", "KH2", "KH3", "GH1", "GH2", "GH3"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.